# Restore errors: "bad header/extent: invalid magic - magic 1701"

Tags: backup, dd, intel, restore

I'm [testing these instructions](http://www.instructables.com/id/BackupRestore-Intel-Edison/?ALLSTEPS) to restore a backup image to an Intel Edison from a previous `.img` image.  The backup line was:

```
dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=sd/ubilinux_image.img
```

I removed a file (to see if it came back following restore) and then ran:

```
dd if=sd/ubilinux_image.img of=/dev/mmcblk0
```

Which returns a continuing [list of repetitive errors](http://pastebin.com/dy6Xx2c4) along the following lines:

```
root@ubilinux:~# dd if=sd/ubilinux_image.img of=/dev/mmcblk0
[ 3771.739948] mmcblk1: error -84 transferring data, sector 16448, nr 32, cmd response 0x900, card status 0xb00
[ 4015.364968] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p8): __ext4_ext_check_block:477: inode #8106: comm rs:main Q:Reg: bad header/extent: invalid magic - magic 1701, entries 0, max 349(0), depth 1(0)
[ 4015.382008] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p8): __ext4_ext_check_block:477: inode #8106: comm rs:main Q:Reg: bad header/extent: invalid magic - magic 1701, entries 0, max 349(0), depth 1(0)
[ 4015.382165] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p8) in ext4_ext_truncate:4402: IO failure
```

I've tried adding the `conv=notrunc` argument with the same result.  Any idea what the problem is here?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: for latest and greatest stuff for Intel Edison better to look here: https://github.com/edison-fw (and wiki: https://htot.github.io/meta-intel-edison/)